# Windows Live Family Safety: how to specify click-through permissions

Tags: windows-7, youtube, parental-controls

I'm trying to setup URL block lists on Microsoft Windows Live Family Safety. Ideally what I would like to do is block direct access to youtube.com but to allow some content from youtube to remain accessible when it is linked to a trusted site.

For example, the site www.zui.com has many links to youtube videos that are appropriate for my kids to watch but since my Windows Live Family Safety account has a block rule for `*.youtube.com/*`, even those videos linked to zui.com are not accessible.

I'm guessing there's no way to achieve what I'm looking for but thought I would put the question out there anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: I've had the same question in regards to Minecraft sites. I don't mind the Minecraft videos, but at the end of every Video, YouTube shows a list of 'Related Content' which includes videos for older people including some R-rated and adult-themed content. I haven't been able to resolve this using Life Family Safety, and I've asked on the forums: [Windows family safety: How to allow a website without allowing embedded YouTube videos?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/windows-family-safety-how-to-allow-a-website/f73e0f40-362b-4e23-a60b-0927a9406dd9)